# Hide Column With Javascript Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have a list with these columns  Question, answer, Issue, Top FAQ, Summary, Q.No. The list is in a webpart on a wiki home page. When the user clicks on the link it brings all fields up. What I want is javascript code so that when user clicks they see question, answer, issue only. I am not what form to add the javascript - display, edit, new form.

Answer (score 1):

If I do not misunderstand you could use jQuery to hide data from the display form (/Lists/YOUR_LIST_NAME/DispForm.aspx). Put the code in a .txt in a Document Library and link it from a Content Editor WebPart, modifying the DispForm page.

An example of code could be:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ms-formtable tbody > tr > td:contains('Top Faq')").closest("tr").hide();
    $(".ms-formtable tbody > tr > td:contains('Q.No')").closest("tr").hide();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this to codeplex this morning! https://lozzisp2013.codeplex.com/

Really simple to use, with more options around disabling and hiding.

```
<script type="text/javasccript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   Lozzi.Fields.disableWithAllowance("Start Date", ["Project Managers"]);
   Lozzi.Fields.disable("Task Status");
   Lozzi.Fields.hideWithAllowance("Predessor");
   Lozzi.Fields.hide("% Complete");
});
</script>
```

Comment: So I understand.  What does the disable do.  in your first lozzi statement, start date the column and project managers the name of the list.  This is put into a .txt document and linked in a content editor webpart in the List < Form Web Parts > Default Display form?

Comment: the disable will take the value and just display it as text, outside of the control, so users can't edit it. See my post, http://davidlozzi.com/2014/01/14/sharepoint-2013-script-hide-or-disable-your-fields/, for more details and a screen shot. The `["Project Managers"]` piece is the name of a SP Group which is allowed to edit it, so it'll disable for all users except for those in the group.